# Перегрузка методов при наследовании stl шаблонов

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, коллекции

Как мне перегрузить оператор `insert()`, чтобы помимо вставки значений в `multimap` выполнялась проверка.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: В порядке бреда, просмотрев ответ от **Monah Tuk** - а как вариант `insert` с другой сигнатурой не годится? типа `insert(..., bool check)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых: готовьтесь к неполиморфному наследованию. Как минимум это означает то, что про обращение через базовый класс - забудьте.

К примеру, у вас будет [такая конструкция](http://ideone.com/pzgf72):

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
class my_multimap : public std::multimap<Key, Value>
{
public:
    using Base = std::multimap<Key, Value>;
    using std::multimap<Key, Value>::multimap; // вытащили конструкторы
    using value_type = typename Base::value_type;

    // далее примерный код
    bool insert(const value_type& val)
    {
        std::cout << "my_multimap::insert(copy)\n";
        if (true /* какая-то проверка */)
            return false;

        Base::insert(val);
        return true;
    }

    // для перемещения
    bool insert(value_type&& val)
    {
        std::cout << "my_multimap::insert(move)\n";
        if (true /* какая-то проверка */)
            return false;

        Base::insert(std::forward<value_type>(val));
        return true;
    }

    //using Base::insert; // вытащили другие методы insert [0]

    // А ещё поглядеть на перегрузки других методов insert:
    //   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/insert/
};
```

Если вы попробуете сделать так:

```
void foo(std::multimap<int, int> &map)
{
  map.insert((std::make_pair(31337,31337)); // [1]
}
...
my_multimap<int,int> my_map;
foo(my_map);
```

то в строчке [1](http://ideone.com/pzgf72) вызовется insert не вашего класса, а базового: класс не полиморфный, а метод не виртуальный. А если раскомментируете строчку [0], то тоже получится забавная картина: вызовется более пригодный базовый метод.

А если вы будете в своём классе создавать какие-то поля, которые потом в конструкторе нужно освобождать, то удаление по базовому классу ещё и к утечке ресурсов приведёт.

Поэтому подумайте дважды, перед тем как делать.

Comment: Вообще, такое наследование нарушает LSP. Так что иделогически лучше композиция (ну или приватное наследование, если совсем лень.)

Comment: Зависит от ситуации. Иногда реальной уточке нужно шильдик на ногу прикрутить. Делать полностью утку для этого ну никакого желания нет, ровно как и открываться от реальной утки. Никто же на сопротивляется неполиморфному наследованию шаблонов в type_traits или наследования от boost::noncopyable (либо аналогов, хотя можно везде писать Foo(Foo) = delete;). Но, положа руку на сердце, мне такое потребовалось ровно один раз, причём через час было убрано :)

Comment: Ну, уточка с шильдиком — как раз хороший пример композиции :) // Несопротивление неправильному наследованию — следствие проблемы с дизайном C++, в котором наследование в смысле «Is-A» намертво спаяно с code sharing. Вот и приходится закрывать глаза на abuse наследования.